# Basics - When setting a div in line, float too?

Tags: xhtml, css

This may be a quick answer for one:

I typically use `display: inline-block;` to set a list of `div`s horizontally.  But I noticed in IE7 it's a no go, the only way around it is using `float: left;` but I lose that relativity position, causing everything else afterwards to push upwards as if it were literally floating on top.  So how can I a achieve the same `display: inline-block;`, so it doesn't "float" and works in IE7 and all the modern day goodness.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the techniques in this article. It may be more than you need for this particular application, but it should work:

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: After all that... I can't help but wonder why we try so desperately hard to avoid tables? What's the benefit, really? You kind of lose your semanticism after all the garbage you have to add to make it work.

Comment: @Mark: Adding a single unnecessary vanilla `div` to a semantic structure is hardly a loss of semantic meaning. The problem with `table` is what it implies to screen readers, spiders, and potential future machine readers of the content; this has no such downside. That said, I do occasionally use `table` for layout, but generally only when I need its layout abilities for a widget somewhere (same-height flexible horizontal boxes, for example), and only when cross-browser is essential. Otherwise, there are better techniques. I can't wait for flexbox to be cross-browser!

Comment: @theazureshadow: The one extra div I can live with, it's the CSS hacks I don't like.

Comment: @Mark: Well, I agree with you there. Perhaps "semantic" wasn't the right word? I agree the complication and maintenance can sometimes be too high a price to pay.

Comment: @theazureshadow: Yes... I suppose poor choice of words, but I never really thought of "divs" as semantic either.

Comment: It's more semantically neutral than anything else, but still definitely possible to overuse. I think you have to weigh the options. At least people aren't using `<b>` quite as often these days for their DOM scripting needs.